# Update data inside a view in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, plsql, view

I have some data that looks as follows

As seen, the req_uri column, has data that contains ids after the second slash. I am only interested in the stem of the uri, that is the part before the second uri.

How can I create a view, where the req_uri is `update`d to only contain values in either `'/v1/org'` or `'/v1/registration'`

```
event_id                                req_uri
0007845f-cf6c-4513-9a5f-96d02482ef78    /v1/org/6970b2a5-e220-4d68-8fc0-2992a1b8bdb7
000a1fb0-ac4d-489e-866a-7c07caebb959    /v1/registration
000fe2a9-6d76-4045-93ac-9df68971539c    /v1/org/6970b2a5-e220-4d68-8fc0-2992a1b8bdb7
0017e50b-c7b5-4e42-b670-f2d9f0af752f    /v1/org/e536c1ed-4822-4b88-8c01-9f14c1c583e3/apps
0025a81f-cf81-4c60-8a39-3a626c1092a3    /v1/org/6970b2a5-e220-4d68-8fc0-2992a1b8bdb7
00304cef-87f3-426b-984c-b0b906b4815a    /v1/org/e536c1ed-4822-4b88-8c01-9f14c1c583e3/apps
```

I know how to create views, as follows

```
CREATE VIEW V_MyView
AS SELECT event_id, req_uri
FROM tableName;
```

I also know how trim it as follows

```
update req_uri set req_uri = '/v1/org' where req_uri like '/v1/org%'
```

However, how can I combine this inside of a view, so that it contains the trimmed data?

Comment: You could do something like `SUBSTRING(req_uri, 1, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('/', req_uri, CHARINDEX('/', req_uri, CHARINDEX('/', req_uri) + 1) + 1), 0) - 1, LEN(req_uri)))` which would always get the first two parts of the req_uri. e.g. "/v1/org" or "/a/b" etc. (Assuming your req_uri always starts with a '/' and you always want the first two).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I follow your question 100%, but I think you are asking how to make a view that has an altered hard-coded manipulation of `req_uri`, so something like this is what you want:

```
CREATE VIEW V_MyView
AS 
SELECT event_id, 
    CASE WHEN req_uri LIKE '/v1/org%' THEN '/v1/org'
      WHEN req_uri LIKE '/v1/registration%' THEN '/v1/registration' 
      ELSE NULL END as [req_uri]
FROM tableName;
```